# How to call my int array class to ad my dropdownlist

Tags: c#, arrays, class

```
public static int[] ddDuration()
{
    int[] ddarray = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    return ddarray;
}
```

How to make in c# to call my int array to who any page in my `DropDownList`

```
//and I am try to show in my DropDownList

//like that some thing

Duration dm = new Duration();
//dm.ddDuration;
//dropdduration.item.AddRang(dm.ddDuration);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got this right, you're trying to add an array of integers as items to a DropDownList.

```
var collection = ddDuration();
int len = collection.length;
for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
    DropDownList1.Items.Insert(i, new ListItem(collection[i].toString(), ""));
}
```

*Insert*'s first parameter is the position (index) in the *Items* collection and the second parameter takes a *[ListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f7h2h8h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)*; of which constructor can be build upon its content (string in this case).